# What is tableName.* in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I can't find the answer of this on the web(probably because google doesn't like special characters), what does a query of this form mean?

```
Select tableName.* FROM tableName
```

I would say it's like `Select * from tableName` but then it would make no sense to add the table name in `Select` statement?

Comment: It's exactly that, and it does make sense when you have more than one table in the query.  But if you have more than one table, it's better to alias them.

Comment: Ok thanks you :) Don't know why someone downvotes here, it's a legitimate question ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT tableName.* 
FROM tableName
```

is exactly that same as

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableName
```

Where it is useful is in a `JOIN`, for example:

```
SELECT table1.*
FROM table1
JOIN table2 ON table1.ID = table2.ID
```

Answer (score 2):

This is useful when you query multiple tables, like:

```
Select a.*, b.someCol
From a
Join b on b.aid = a.id
```

Comment: Well, it *could* be a table alias, but not necessarily.